# high cpu utilization of a node app

Tags: node.js, v8

My node app (running through webpack dev server) is taking up 60% cpu consistently. From the cpu profile, looks like call to `_proc_listpidspath` is the culprit. Any hints on what is this function call for, and how to find which node library calls this.

thanks.

See the profile below.

```
Code move event for unknown code: 0x19cac90226c0
Code move event for unknown code: 0x19cac90b3360
Code move event for unknown code: 0x19caca55d3a0
Statistical profiling result from isolate-0x102004c00-v8.log, (209273 ticks, 2592 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   6896    3.3%          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    285    0.1%          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
    332    0.2%    0.2%  KeyedLoadIC: A keyed load IC from the snapshot {1}
    287    0.1%    0.1%  Stub: LoadICStub
    ....
    ....
  [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   5271    2.5%    2.6%  JavaScript
  194229   92.8%   96.1%  C++
   1481    0.7%    0.7%  GC
   7181    3.4%          Shared libraries
   2592    1.2%          Unaccounted
[C++]:
  ticks  total  nonlib   name
 162560   77.7%   80.4%  _proc_listpidspath
  4417    2.1%    2.2%  _uv_timer_stop
  1683    0.8%    0.8%  _heap_node_swap
  1274    0.6%    0.6%  _timer_cb
  1006    0.5%    0.5%  _hex
   762    0.4%    0.4%  _uv_fs_stat
   704    0.3%    0.3%  _mach_vm_map
   677    0.3%    0.3%  _szone_check_all
   654    0.3%    0.3%  _pthread_join$NOCANCEL
   637    0.3%    0.3%  __pthread_exit
   583    0.3%    0.3%  _uv__run_timers
   583    0.3%    0.3%  _dec
   ......
   ......

[Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
 Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
 amount of its parent calls.
 Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

  ticks parent  name
 162560   77.7%  _proc_listpidspath

  6896    3.3%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib

  4417    2.1%  _uv_timer_stop
```

Edit:

I could isolate this to when it happens. I started using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) yesterday. Now, if I remove my `node_modules` and run `npm -i` to install all the deps through npm client, I see the file count inside `node_modules` as

```
node_modules ❯❯❯ find . -print | wc -l                                                                                                                                   master
   43058
```

If I remove, `node_modules` and ran `~/.yarn/bin/yarn.js`, then

```
node_modules ❯❯❯ find . -print | wc -l                                                                                                                                 ⏎ master
   32138
```

so, there is a difference in files installed by both cli, and yarn installs less. But, the cpu with yarn is 80% in idle (webpack server in watch mode), and 1% with npm.!!

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: From [this](http://opensource.apple.com//source/Libc/Libc-498/darwin/proc_listpidspath.c) I'm getting the idea that you may be using `fs.watch()` or `fs.watchFile()`.

Comment: Please see the edits. It is probably webpack watch, and the os is Mac OSX.

Comment: Might be worthwhile creating an issue for this (if you can reproduce it on a smaller scale).

Answer (score 0):

This may due to `chokidar` being skipped by yarn.
These issues are open at the `yarnpkg` tracker and awaiting for a fix.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1009
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/629

Comment: This isn't an appropriately formatted answer for SO.   Link-only resolutions can go away and not provide benefit in the future.  You shoulkd at least provide minimal solution in the answer.